# Smart search filter not working

Tags: joomla-3.x, search, smartsearch, content-filtering, filter

I am using a filter on a smart searchbar, I only want to search for tags, categories and articles.

When I am using the filter and I search for example tags, it won't show any result.

If I deactivate the filter then everything will show but then it won't be filtered anymore...

How can I make the filter work and show results ?

Filtered :

[image]
Unfiltered :
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to JSE, MatB. Please take our [tour] while you wait for feedback/support.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thank you for the welcome !

Answer (score 2):

Probably you didn't run the indexer that's why smart search doesn't show any results.

Here are the steps you should follow for the smart search to work (probably you should go to the fifth step directly):

1. After you log in to the administrator area click on the Extensions →
   Plug-in Manager menu item.
2. Next, filter the plug-in list so that only Smart Search plug-ins are
   shown. This can be done by selecting "finder" from the "Select Type"
   filter drop-down.
3. Now, enable the plugins you want to use for your site and disable
   the rest.
4. Click on the Components → Smart Search menu item.
5. **Click on the Index button in the toolbar to start the indexer**. This
   will cause a modal window to load with some indexer status
   information and a progress bar. Indexing is complete
   when the progress bar disappears and you see a message indicating
   that it is now safe to close the modal window.

Here is a more complete guide about smart search in Joomla: [Smart Search quickstart guide](https://docs.joomla.org/Smart_Search_quickstart_guide)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response, I have already used the indexer, the progress bar is stuck at 90% everytime,then I close the window and it still indexes everything. But the filter is not working though. I don't know what causes this issue :/

Comment: Probably it's a PHP fault. You should debug and check the error logs and update your question if you need more help.

Comment: I'll try to look into that, thanks !